# Understand fprintf syntax

Tags: c, printf

I know very little about C, but am trying to understand a programme written in it.

I've come across this line, but am unsure what it means:

```
fprintf(kinsh.fp, "%-.*lg", ndigits, kins[i+j*n]);
```

I think this means "Print a number with *ndigits* decimal places or significant figures (whichever is shorter) to *kinsh* (which is a file). However, I don't know what *kins*, which is an array, is doing in there.

Have I misunderstood - in context, it would make more sense if the line is reading from *kinsh* and writing into *kins*?

Comment: That's the thing you are printing.  The value of kins with that index of i+j*n;  Read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fprintf function is defined as follows :

```
int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
```

So, `kinsh.fp` is the `FILE` pointer. 
Now the format string `"%-.*lg"` is a C format string which implies this :

1. The `-` implies left alignment
2. Anything after the `.` implies the precision.
3. The `*` implies that the precision is not hardcoded but provided as a parameter which is the first parameter after the format string i.e. `ndigits`.
4. The `lg` will be treated by C99 compiler as `double`, `Lg` is for long double. (As mentioned by @mafso in comments, `lg` is Undefined Behaviour in C89)
5. The actual data is in `kins[i+j*n]`.

**Edit**

What is does :
The statement writes a `long double` value stored at `kins[i+j*n]`, with `ndigits` precision and left alignment, in the file pointed by `kinsh.fp`.

The general format string format is : `%[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type`

Comment: `%lg` means `double` in C99 (same as `%g`) and is UB in C89.

Comment: @mafso: I see, updating the answer accordingly.